# Como hacer que mi archivo de excel tome encuenta las comas en un json que estoy generando desde java?

Tags: java, json, jsf

tengo un problema a la de exportar mi archivo (reporte) en java, el problema es que me omite las comas, cuando se genera el archivo el json si sale bien, este es mi codigo:

DAO implement:

```
 @Override
    public List<Current_informationsDTO> getReportCurrent_information(Date date1, Date date2,  String cves) {
        try {
            List<Current_informationsDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            ConnectionDB conn = new ConnectionDB();
            System.out.println("date1..." + date1);
            System.out.println("date2..." + date2);
            //System.out.println("typeReport..." + typeReport);
            System.out.println("cves..." + cves);
            List<ParametersSP> parametros = new ArrayList<>();
            //parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", Integer.parseInt(Session.getOriginAdmActiva())));
            //parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", typeReport));
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", df.format(date1)));
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", df.format(date2)));
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", cves));
            ResultSet res = conn.ExecuteFunctionQuery("sp_get_reports_currents_informations", parametros);

            if (res.next()) {
                System.out.println("Que esta regresando res..." + res);

                String s = res.getString(1);//Se guarda json que viene del sp

                System.out.println("Que trae la s..." + s);
                s = s.replace("'T'", "");
                s = s.replace("null", "-");
                list = gson.fromJson(s, new TypeToken<List<Current_informationsDTO>>() {

                }.getType());
//                 for (Current_informationsDTO item : list) {
//                     System.out.println("Que viene null" + item.getVehiculo());
//                }
                }
            return list;


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Mi metodo del bean:

```
public void report_Current_Information(TrackingReportTemplateVO temp, String jsonCves) {
        Current_InformationsDAO services = new Current_InformationsDAOImpl();
        List<Current_informationsDTO> elements = services.getReportCurrent_information(dateT1, dateT2, jsonCves);
        ReporterTraking<Current_informationsDTO, Current_informationsDTO> aux = new ReporterTraking(elements, temp.getFields_template(), null);
        ReportInterface ri = new ReportInterface() {
            @Override
            public void resolveConditions() {
                if (aux.conditions == null || aux.conditions.isEmpty()) {

                    for (Current_informationsDTO element : elements) {
                        aux.elementsFiltered.add(element);
                    }
                }
                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };
        aux.setResolver(ri);
        report = aux;
        report.resolveConditions();

        showReport = true;
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:panelReportedTableData");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("panelReportedTableData");

    }
```

Por ultimo este es el metodo java que se ejecuta cuando descargo el archivo en la aplicación:

```
 public void formatExcel(Object doc) {
        HSSFWorkbook book = (HSSFWorkbook) doc;
        for (int i = 0; i < book.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            HSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(i);
            HSSFCellStyle intStyle = book.createCellStyle();
            intStyle.setDataFormat((short) 1);

            HSSFCellStyle decStyle = book.createCellStyle();
            decStyle.setDataFormat((short) 2);

            HSSFCellStyle dollarStyle = book.createCellStyle();
            dollarStyle.setDataFormat((short) 7);

            HSSFCellStyle stringStyle = book.createCellStyle();
            stringStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("@"));

            for (int rowInd = 1; rowInd < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); rowInd++) {
                HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowInd);
                for (int cellInd = 1; cellInd < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); cellInd++) {
                    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellInd);

                    //This is sortof a hack to counter PF exporting all data as text
                    //We capture the existing value as string, convert to int, 
                    //then format the cell to be numeric and reset the value to be int
                    String strVal = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();

                    //this has to be done to temporarily blank out the cell value
                    //because setting the type to numeric directly will cause 
                    //an IllegalStateException because POI stupidly thinks
                    //the cell is text because it was exported as such by PF...
                    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);



                    if (StringUtils.countMatches(strVal, ".") < 2) {
                        strVal = strVal.replace(",", StringUtils.EMPTY);
                    }

                    strVal = strVal.replace("%", StringUtils.EMPTY);
                    if ("".equals(strVal)) {
                        cell.setCellValue("-");
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if (strVal.contains(",")) {
                        cell.setCellValue(strVal);
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if (strVal.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")) {
                        cell.setCellValue(strVal);
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if (strVal.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {
                        cell.setCellValue(strVal);
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if (strVal.contains(":")) {
                        cell.setCellValue(strVal);
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if ((strVal.contains("-") && strVal.contains(":")) || "-".equals(strVal) || strVal.contains(";")) {
                        cell.setCellValue(strVal);
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if (strVal.length() >= 10) {
                        cell.setCellValue(strVal);
                        cell.setCellStyle(stringStyle);
                    } else if (strVal.indexOf('.') == -1) {
                        //integer
                        //numStyle.setDataFormat((short)1);
                        int intVal = Integer.valueOf(strVal);

                         cell.setCellStyle(intStyle);
                        cell.setCellValue(intVal);
                    } else {
                        //double
                        if (strVal.startsWith("$")) {
                            strVal = strVal.replace("$", StringUtils.EMPTY);
                            //numStyle.setDataFormat((short)5);
                            cell.setCellStyle(dollarStyle);

                        } else {
                            //numStyle.setDataFormat((short)2);
                            cell.setCellStyle(decStyle);
                        }

                        double dblVal = Double.valueOf(strVal);
                        cell.setCellValue(dblVal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y este es el json:

```
[{"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   104,249.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE-EDUARDO NAVA VERASTICO", "vehiculo": "TT1212 RHINO-208AE3", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "San Luis Río Colorado - Mexicali 1901, Ex-Ejido Coahuila, 21360 Mexicali, B.C., México", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 20:33:32", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.604053, -115.427462"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    65,973.00", "operador": "AAP0 ENRIQUE MARTINEZ VIERA", "vehiculo": "TT3137 RHINO-376DE7", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "La Venta 13, Industrial Cuamatla, 54730 Cuautitlán Izcalli, Méx., México", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 20:52:50", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.665502, -99.20383"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    48,744.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1303 RHINO-610EX5", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "21380, Carr a San Felipe 30, Xochimilco, Mexicali, B.C., Mexico", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:36:20", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.601793, -115.435935"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    40,907.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1120 RHINO-013AH2", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "Felipe Loza 18, La Llave, 45618 San Pedro Tlaquepaque, Jal., México", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 20:45:15", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.575982, -103.338658"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    39,441.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3204 RHINO-883ES3", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "1423:14:53", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:33:29", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.57325, -100.262215"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    94,283.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE-NAZARIO AVILA GOMEZ", "vehiculo": "TT1221 RHINO-263AK5", "velocidad": "6.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:21", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.417132, -116.92278"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    62,299.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1232 RHINO-534AR1", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:58:24", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.56079, -100.923498"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    84,068.00", "operador": "AAP0 FELIPE YANEZ MONTIEL", "vehiculo": "TT3169 RHINO-073DH7", "velocidad": "56.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:48", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.52868, -99.014435"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    70,374.00", "operador": "AAP0 ERWIN PIEDAD HERNANDEZ SUAREZ", "vehiculo": "TT3149 RHINO-685DG2", "velocidad": "14.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:12:13", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.75339, -99.129282"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    70,390.00", "operador": "AAP0 CESAR CRUZ REYES", "vehiculo": "TT1398 RHINO-86AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:21", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.67579, -100.19085"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    13,851.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3159 RHINO-884DH2", "velocidad": "2.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:23", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.460063, -99.038303"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    70,361.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE RICARDO LOPEZ GONZALEZ", "vehiculo": "TT1203 RHINO-802AE2", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:38", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.517208, -116.936898"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   122,990.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3172 RHINO-866DH7", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 20:33:09", "ultimascoordenadas": "16.886762, -99.831638"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   109,180.00", "operador": "AAP0 ALFONSO GONZALEZ HERVER", "vehiculo": "TT1302 RHINO-609EX5", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 08:37:44", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.602468, -115.43593"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    94,766.00", "operador": "AAP0 CUAUHTEMOC TAPIA ESTRADA", "vehiculo": "TT2187 RHINO-169AK7", "velocidad": "45.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:38", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.923955, -89.687767"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    28,923.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1375 RHINO-34AE8G", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:46", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.144658, -98.220312"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   113,050.00", "operador": "AAP0 CARLOS PACHECO ALBERTO", "vehiculo": "TT1393 RHINO-91AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "1423:14:53", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:33", "ultimascoordenadas": "24.664908, -101.716155"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    29,776.00", "operador": "AAP0 ENRIQUE REA CRUZ", "vehiculo": "TT3138 RHINO-375DE7", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "1423:14:53", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:52:20", "ultimascoordenadas": "21.06056, -101.560538"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   101,565.00", "operador": "AAP0 ABEL HERNANDEZ ALVARADO", "vehiculo": "TT1234 RHINO-536AR1", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:12:05", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.840863, -100.413635"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    34,718.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE  GERARDO BUCIO SUASTEGUI", "vehiculo": "TT1207 RHINO-209AE3", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:16:47", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.602115, -115.43619"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    48,077.00", "operador": "AAP0 CIPRIANO REYES ANGELES", "vehiculo": "TT1404 RHINO-98AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:43", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.608338, -100.863272"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   124,053.00", "operador": "AAP0 ARIEL FERNANDO RAMIREZ AVALOS", "vehiculo": "TT1322 RHINO-01AA4V", "velocidad": "75.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:10:56", "ultimascoordenadas": "17.912425, -94.900768"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    75,644.00", "operador": "AAP0 FELIPE DE J ORTEGA GARCIA", "vehiculo": "TT3163 RHINO-513DH6", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:09:32", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.666005, -99.204715"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    53,906.00", "operador": "AAP0 ARTURO GARCIA FLORES", "vehiculo": "TT1324 RHINO-97AA3V", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:33", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.61317, -100.862572"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    93,908.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1330 RHINO-33AA4V", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:26", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.577367, -115.355858"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    71,403.00", "operador": "AAP0 AGUSTIN VIGUERAS SERRANO", "vehiculo": "TT1259 RHINO-55AF6L", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:34", "ultimascoordenadas": "28.66081, -106.078637"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    54,417.00", "operador": "AAP0 ALEJANDRO OLIVARES BELTRA", "vehiculo": "TT1299 RHINO-134EU9", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 07:03:20", "ultimascoordenadas": "32.602377, -115.436357"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    94,395.00", "operador": "AAP0 CHRISTIAN DE JESUS MUNOZ", "vehiculo": "TT1402 RHINO-01AG7A", "velocidad": "80.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:37", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.581773, -102.731985"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    59,066.00", "operador": "AAP0 FRANCISCO TELLEZ ESCOBAR", "vehiculo": "TT3202 RHINO-884ES3", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:12:57", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.758697, -99.12644"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    85,876.00", "operador": "AHR0-E JESUS ROMAN TERAN", "vehiculo": "TT1392 RHINO-92AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:51", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.653405, -100.117655"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    65,885.00", "operador": "AAP0 ARTURO S. CAMPOS DOMINGUE", "vehiculo": "TT1358 RHINO-15AE2A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:37", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.613843, -100.861977"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    52,810.00", "operador": "AAP0 FERNANDO CARDENAS GARCIA", "vehiculo": "TT3174 RHINO-817AL7", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "1423:14:53", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:25:35", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.665878, -99.205415"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   119,805.00", "operador": "AAP0 CESAR IVAN MONROY MARQUEZ", "vehiculo": "TT1399 RHINO-04AG7A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:24", "ultimascoordenadas": "23.326183, -98.84892"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    90,971.00", "operador": "AAP0 GENARO MONROY TREJO", "vehiculo": "TT3206 RHINO-218EX2", "velocidad": "72.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:12:03", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.42179, -100.05011"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    67,289.00", "operador": "AAP0 FERNANDO CRUZ PARRA", "vehiculo": "TT3175 RHINO-390AP1", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:34:08", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.665403, -99.203975"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    71,927.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3152 RHINO-874DG3", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:43", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.733348, -99.392133"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    54,100.00", "operador": "AAP0 ENRIQUE CRISOSTOMO ORTIZ", "vehiculo": "TT3136 RHINO-377DE7", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:54:33", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.665933, -99.205405"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    90,323.00", "operador": "AAP0 ARTURO LOPEZ VELAZQUEZ", "vehiculo": "TT1326 RHINO-95AA3V", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:12:59", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.726497, -100.53529"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    75,475.00", "operador": "AAP0 FRANCISCO JAVIER GARCIA A", "vehiculo": "TT3195 RHINO-685AT3", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:26", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.665723, -99.20339"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   166,490.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1376 RHINO-33AE8G", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:08", "ultimascoordenadas": "17.885573, -93.144855"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    62,093.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3134 RHINO-837DE1", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 20:58:56", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.459465, -99.038475"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   114,855.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE ARTURO PURECO SERVIN", "vehiculo": "TT1128 RHINO-020AH2", "velocidad": "60.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:19", "ultimascoordenadas": "24.75027, -107.462548"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    49,798.00", "operador": "AAP0 ALEJANDRO CAMACHO ESTRADA", "vehiculo": "TT1294 RHINO-117EU9", "velocidad": "57.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:39", "ultimascoordenadas": "27.898808, -101.165398"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    80,697.00", "operador": "AHR0-E JOSE BENITO CECENA ESQUER", "vehiculo": "TT3199 RHINO-882ER8", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:46:11", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.665948, -99.205395"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    65,740.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3186 RHINO-105AR4", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:45:22", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.231158, -99.84854"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    25,673.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3129 RHINO-767DD5", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:02:05", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.66557, -99.203448"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    77,306.00", "operador": "AAP0 GUSTAVO GONZALEZ AMBROCIO", "vehiculo": "TT3228 RHINO-71AE7X", "velocidad": "13.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:12:00", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.565518, -100.300465"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    58,932.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE FIDEL SALGADO LORENZO", "vehiculo": "TT1129 RHINO-021AH2", "velocidad": "41.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:04", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.524127, -105.30959"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    63,534.00", "operador": "AAP0 CIRILO GOMEZ REYES", "vehiculo": "TT1407 RHINO-95AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:19", "ultimascoordenadas": "27.94019, -101.279848"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   167,453.00", "operador": "AAP0 DOMINGO SANCHEZ MENDOZA", "vehiculo": "TT2204 RHINO-321ET5", "velocidad": "69.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:32", "ultimascoordenadas": "17.789627, -92.692653"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    26,130.00", "operador": "AAC0-EE ALBERTO REBOLLAR BETANCOURT", "vehiculo": "RN1005 RHINO-784DX7", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:52:27", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.707415, -103.446268"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    85,612.00", "operador": "AAP0 ALEJANDRO VILLEGAS LOZANO", "vehiculo": "TT1301 RHINO-608EX5", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:31", "ultimascoordenadas": "31.845783, -116.562122"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   114,841.00", "operador": "AAP0 ARTURO JUAREZ CRUZ", "vehiculo": "TT1325 RHINO-96AA3V", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:32", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.697757, -100.127358"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    70,255.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3192 RHINO-925AT3", "velocidad": "37.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:51", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.988597, -99.183177"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   110,033.00", "operador": "AAP0 CHRISTIAN SALDANA DIMAS", "vehiculo": "TT1403 RHINO-99AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:22", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.610298, -100.864225"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    97,840.00", "operador": "AAP0 ERICK EDUARDO VACA CASARR", "vehiculo": "TT3144 RHINO-906DF2", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:49", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.913405, -99.23714"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   139,017.00", "operador": "AAP0 DAN ESTRELLA MARTINEZ", "vehiculo": "TT2190 RHINO-921AF6", "velocidad": "78.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:35", "ultimascoordenadas": "20.97007, -89.565658"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   119,087.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT3183 RHINO-109AR4", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 19:36:43", "ultimascoordenadas": "16.8883, -99.829888"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   106,023.00", "operador": "AAP0 ALFREDO MENDOZA PRECIADO", "vehiculo": "TT1309 RHINO-616EX5", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:17", "ultimascoordenadas": "25.775718, -100.463763"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "     8,292.00", "operador": "AHR0-E JESUS ANTONIO MORENO GRIJALV", "vehiculo": "TT1365 RHINO-40AE8G", "velocidad": "30.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:13:36", "ultimascoordenadas": "19.086992, -98.206615"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   112,437.00", "operador": "-", "vehiculo": "TT1406 RHINO-96AG6A", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "1423:14:53", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 21:51:50", "ultimascoordenadas": "27.89018, -101.152258"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "   116,046.00", "operador": "AAP0 ARTURO MEZA ANGELES", "vehiculo": "TT1329 RHINO-32AA4V", "velocidad": "0.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:09:04", "ultimascoordenadas": "30.692502, -115.986772"}, {"grupo": "HOLCIM", "semana": "4", "empresa": "GST", "odometro": "    72,380.00", "operador": "AAP0 FILIBERTO PARRA HERNANDEZ", "vehiculo": "TT3185 RHINO-107AR4", "velocidad": "6.0", "horasmotor": "0", "localizacion": "-", "ultimo_mensaje": "23-01-2019 22:07:48", "ultimascoordenadas": "16.888053, -99.829597"}]
```

Principalmente en el parametro de odometro en el json de arriba es donde se genera cierto numero por 2,998.00, pero el problema que desde el excel omite la coma y lo genera asi: 2998.00

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, la verdad este problema nunca me lo habia topado hasta ahorita, saludos y quedo al pendiente.

Comment: Tu pregunta se refiere a 'acentos' y planteas que quieres 'comas'. Modifica tu pregunta para que se adapte a lo que realmente quieres. Saludos

Comment: Hola que tal, si es verdad una disculpa XD, ya modifiqué mi pregunta

Comment: Por cierto, lo que deseas es que te muestre las comas en la celda en el archivo de Excel. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Asi, es que ya que en cuando genero el reporte en la vista si se muestras pero ya cuando esporto a excel los omite

Comment: Crees que si estableces el formato de celda para que te muestre las 'comas' el problema se resuelva?. A mi entender, es correcto que exporte los números en formato `eeeeee.dddd` donde `e` son los enteros y `d` los decimales. El formato de visualización en la hoja de Excel es algo que debes implementar tu. No se si me explico.

Comment: Asi es, el codigo del metodo donde se genera ya estaba estaba ahi, algunas cosas no comprendo para que son,  es algo del dataformat, he estado investigando pero no doy con la solución :(

Comment: Esta linea es la que establece el tipo de dato numérico `cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);`. Luego en la siguiente linea se eliminan las comas. Empieza por allí.

Comment: El problema que ahi es donde en otro lado se ocupa, es decir, un ejm que si comento solo esa linea, que seria esta: strVal = strVal.replace(",", StringUtils.EMPTY); , en otros reportes que si ocupan ese les va a afectar, ahora si que estoy entre la espalda y la pared :(